# Li not showing right in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html-lists

I'm having yet another problem with Internet Explorer. I have a list i got from my php database and i want to show it in a div. There's no problem with any browser, except for Internet explorer. The li's are squashed under eachother. I have no idea why.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks in IE: http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3435/fkngie.jpg

Edit: added zip file with all related files: http://www.mediafire.com/?pgx1yg79c80a8sd

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle of the html and css structure?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/SkVB4/2/ The list itself however is from the database, so i'm not sure how i can show the php?

Comment: just grab what the html looks like in the browser (ie look at the source using "view source" or IE developer tool)

Comment: Here is a zipfile with all the related html css and php file: mediafire.com/?pgx1yg79c80a8sd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to specify div's size as 100% in style. Unless you send generated HTML code, there is nothing more any one can do.

Can you just save and upload html file, and any css files related?

EDIT:
I checked your file, after replacing database parts with static text, it is working fine in IE 6. However, I think your problem raises from divs. You may try to debugging your divs by assigning different bg colors to them. Also check your database if it contains some text that can break markup.

Comment: Here is a zipfile with all the related html css and php file: http://www.mediafire.com/?pgx1yg79c80a8sd

Comment: Thanks man, i appreciate the help! I'll be trying the stuff you suggested tomorrow, since int's past midnight here. What kind of characters in my database/php should i look after that can break markup?

Comment: <, >, &, character can break your markup, you need to escape them, search html entities. Im not sure if it was the right function, but it can direct you to the right one even if it doesnt.